# Libgdx Actions.parallel not working

Tags: java, libgdx

I want my LoadingScreen to **simultaneously** load my Assets/Generate fonts and show a fadeIn/fadeOut-sequence of a LoadingScreenImage

However, *Actions.parallel(...)* doen't seem to work. If i check the console after adding a few *System.out.println()* it clearly says that the two actions are executed like a sequence. Running the code, i get a black screen first, until the assets are loaded/generated and then the fadeIn/fadeOut-action kicks in

Code:

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen{
private Stage stage;
private Image image;
private FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
private FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
private boolean load;

@Override
public void show(){
    Assets.manager = new AssetManager();
    stage = new Stage();
    Assets.loadingScreen = new Texture("LoadingScreen.png");
    image = new Image(Assets.loadingScreen);
    stage.addActor(image);
    // ...

    Action loadAssets = new Action(){
        @Override
        public boolean act(float delta){
            if(load){
                load = false;
                generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("res/fonts/TUNGAB.TTF"));
                parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

                // ... fonts are generated here

                generator.dispose();
                Assets.manager.finishLoading();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    Action completeAction = new Action(){
        @Override
        public boolean act(float delta) {
            game.setScreen(new MenuScreen());
            return true;
        }
    };

    load = true;
    SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction(Actions.alpha(0), Actions.fadeIn(0.4f), Actions.delay(1.1f), Actions.fadeOut(0.4f), completeAction);
    stage.addAction(Actions.parallel(loadAssets, sequenceAction));
}

@Override
public void render(float dt){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
}
@Override
public void pause(){
}
@Override
public void resume(){
}
@Override
public void hide(){
}
@Override
public void dispose(){
    stage.dispose();
    Assets.loadingScreen.dispose();
}
```

}

What am i missing?

Comment: Actions.parralel does not actually run actions in parralel. See here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/ParallelAction.java#L63 It just combines them and runs 'act' on them each frame until they are all done. E.g. when you want something to bounce and turn yellow at the same time.

Comment: so i'd have to create a new thread and load my Assets in the background then?

Comment: Yes, though unfortunaly for graphical assets you NEED the main thread where OpenGL lives. So in my use case I downloaded images from the internet and loaded them into the GPU in the main thread. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Assets.manager.finishLoading() blocks everything until all assets are loaded. That is why I believe you get this behaviour. Other than that your actions seem correct! If you remove that line i believe you will see that the 2 actions actually are in parallel.

You can add a repeated action for loadAssets action and use Assets.manager.update() until all assets are updated. When the fonts are loaded then you can remove the action from the stage.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for the correction, sir. However i still don't get the behavior i want. I changed the code to [this](http://pastebin.com/KuaHTrM6)

But the console prints the following order: 
generate,
Starting Font-Generation,
Ending Font-Generation,
sequence,
generate,
sequence,
generate,
sequence,
generate,
sequence,
...
                        But i want it to start the sequenceAction **while** the fonts are generated

Answer (score 0):

Change `Assets.manager.finishLoading();` to `Assets.manager.update();` so it doesn't block the thread to complete loading of everything. And since you want it to repeatedly call `update` until it's done, you don't want to return true until `update` returns true. So also your `load` variable should stay true until the loading is done.

You can move your `load`, `generator`, and `parameter` declarations inside the anonymous Action class, since that's the only place you need them. Below, I inverted `load` and changed the name to `done` to be less ambiguous.

And finally, you don't want to be recreating the font generator over and over. You can break up the sequence of things to load with a switch statement. The last part of the switch can be the repeated calls to the asset manager. Now each time `act` is called on the action (once per frame), it will only do one of the steps instead of all of them.

```
Action loadAssets = new Action(){
    private boolean done = false;
    private int steps = 0;
    private FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
    private FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;

    @Override
    public boolean act(float delta){
        if(!done){
            switch (steps){
                case 0:
                    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("res/fonts/TUNGAB.TTF"));
                    parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
                    steps++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //generate first font
                    steps++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //generate second font
                    steps++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //and so on
                    steps++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    generator.dispose();
                    steps++;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    done = Assets.manager.update();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return done;
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried your workaround, problem is that the fadeIn-Effect of my LoadingScreen-logo then stutters. It's not continuous.

Comment: I think that's as small as the steps can be broken up, which results in stuttering. I haven't used FreeTypeFontGenerator, but I imagine it takes a while to generate each font, which will lead to stutter.  I would recommend removing the font generation from this action and into a new action that runs in sequence after your parallel asset manager and fade in actions.

Comment: Once your logo fades in, the screen's not changing, so you can allow the fonts to block the thread and load all at once like you had them before. So your actions become something like `sequence(parallel(loadAssets, fadeIn(0.4f)), loadFonts, fadeOut(0.4f), completeAction)`.

Comment: Thanks, i decided to go for this solution because i get the effect i want. New sequence: sequence(alpha(0), fadeIn(0.4f), loadAssets, fadeOut(0.4f), completeAction)
loadAssets-Action generates the fonts and calls Assets.manager.finishLoading()

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as you.

**Edit** Not quite, as you not necessarily want to run things in parallel but just want your UI thread to not freeze up. In that case you will find your answer here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#loading-assets

More specifically this piece of code:

```
public void render() {
  if(manager.update()) {
     // we are done loading, let's move to another screen!
  }

  // display loading information
  float progress = manager.getProgress()
  ... left to the reader ...
}
```

What I think this does is load a little bit of the assets every time you call `update()`. Untill it is done loading everything. This is necessary because loading textures requires OpenGL context (i.e. it must be done on the main thread).

You could use the code below though to load non-OpenGL assets in a separate, dedicated thread.

**'Old' answer:**

So I created the following simple class:

```
public abstract class ReadyRunnable implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Flag whether we're ready
     */
    protected boolean ready = false;

    /**
     * Are we ready yet?
     *
     * @return
     */
    public final boolean isReady() {
        return this.ready;
    }

    /**
     * Method run when {@link ReadyRunnable#run()} is done
     */
    public abstract void ready();

}
```

It is used in my loading screen as such:

```
public class LoadScreen extends BaseScreen {

   private ReadyRunnable runner;

   [...] // Create a nice loading bar etc.

   public void render() {
       if(runner.isReady()) runner.ready();
   }

}
```

Then when I need to load something:

```
this.setScreen(new LoadScreen(new ReadyRunnable() {

    public void run() {
       // Do your loading here in parallel (outside the UI thread)

       this.ready = true;
    }

    public void ready() {
        // This actually runs in the main thread!
    }
}));
```